vb.net Windows Authentication Broker For Simpler User Logins With MSAL
I am trying to authenticate with Windows Authentication Broker With MSAL but I get an error when trying to get the console or terminal window.
Private Async Sub Auth()
     Dim scopes As String() = {"User.Read"}
     Dim options As New BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows)
     Dim storageProperties As StorageCreationProperties = New StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder("cache.bin", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Build()

     Dim app As IPublicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder _
     .Create("ClientID") _
     .WithBroker(options) _
     .WithParentActivityOrWindow(GetConsoleOrTerminalWindow) _
     .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common") _
     .WithDefaultRedirectUri() _
     .Build()

     Dim cacheHelper As MsalCacheHelper = Await MsalCacheHelper.CreateAsync(storageProperties)
     cacheHelper.RegisterCache(app.UserTokenCache)

     Dim accounts As IReadOnlyList(Of IAccount) = Await app.GetAccountsAsync()
     Dim existingAccount As IAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault()

     Dim result As AuthenticationResult

     Try
         result = If(existingAccount IsNot Nothing,
     Await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, existingAccount).ExecuteAsync(),
     Await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync())
     Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     End Try

 End Sub

 <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
 Private Shared Function GetAncestor(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal flags As GetAncestorFlags) As IntPtr
 End Function

 <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
 Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
 End Function

 Enum GetAncestorFlags
     GetParent = 1
     GetRoot = 2
     GetRootOwner = 3
 End Enum

 Public Function GetConsoleOrTerminalWindow() As IntPtr
     Dim consoleHandle As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()
     Dim handle As IntPtr = GetAncestor(consoleHandle, GetAncestorFlags.GetRootOwner)
     Return handle
 End Function

The error I experience is:
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'WithParentActivityOrWindow' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Overloads Function WithParentActivityOrWindow(windowFunc As Func(Of IntPtr)) As PublicClientApplicationBuilder': Value of type 'IntPtr' cannot be converted to 'Func(Of IntPtr)'.
Any help would be appreciated.

In VB, you need to use the AddressOf operator to indicate that you want to treat a method as a delegate, because the parentheses are optional on a call with no arguments (so a bare appearance is treated as such a call).

I feel like this should be a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find a good target.
